# is there a way to show the the post title after the image?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, post-meta, content

Trying to show the post title after the image in the main blog page and single page, I have tried to edit the content.php but unable to achive the result I need, which is basiscally

```
IMAGE
TITLE
META 
CONTENT
```

I have tried to change the code in content.php but only managed to get the title to show below the image but also below the content

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <div class="featured-post">
        <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="comments-link">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->


    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
            <div class="author-info">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                <div class="author-description">
                    <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="author-link">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                            <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .author-link -->
                </div><!-- .author-description -->
            </div><!-- .author-info -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: Forgot to mention...I am trying to do this in the twentytwelve theme

Answer (score 1):

Look at: http://pastebin.com/2mKXyKa9

I've moved the content beneath the meta, so you have the order...

```
 1. IMAGE
 2. TITLE
 3. META
 4. CONTENT
```

...as it currently stands, the partial snippet you pasted above has the content being called above the thumbnail. Also you are missed the block which contains the meta content, so it makes your questions a little confusing. I've done the best to assume what you want is in the [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/2mKXyKa9) above, if not, please clarify your question or snippet.

Comment: Hi userabuser, I updated the snippet to the to all the code on that page...hopefully this clarifies the question a bit more, It seems the code from pastebin is not updating the order of the post content yet